# disable onclick ads with a content-script in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, popup, ads, userscripts

There are some video streaming sites that pop up an ad anytime you click anywhere on the page. The problem is, you have to click on the page to press play! So I was thinking of making a UserScript that disables the script that does this. The only problem is, I already disable all the scripts on the site and when I do it still pops up. Is there a way that I can disable them ? I'm also using jQuery, so if I can do it through their interface, that would be great.

edit: Two perfect examples of such sites are daclips.in and gorrilavid.in

Comment: Could you provide an example of such a site?

Comment: " I already disable all the scripts on the site and when I do it still pops up" Either you didn't disable them all or it's a simple HTML popup

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details.  This question is way too vague.  "Pop ups" can be one of several things.  Anyway, I suspect that you need one of the many flash-blocking extensions.

Comment: Sorry, I should've provided an example. I updated my original post.

Comment: Still need more details.  I see no pop-ups (I've lots of blockers installed).  Do you mean the 5-second "wait" page?  Please memorize [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: No, I do not mean the wait page. I already handled that. What I meant was that when you click anywhere on the page and you do not have an adblocker (which I don't), it pops us an ad. Since I already wrote a userscript for skipping the wait, I wanted to extend it to take care of the popup ads.

Comment: please post the code you already tried.

Answer (score 3):

I have Adblocker Plus, and it seems like it is not recognizing "on Click" events as pop-ups, rather normal clicked links. And the logic is simple, no Adblocker will block you from clicking something intentionally and it (the link) opening in another window/tab.

The problem is the new window contains your clicked Url, while the original window/tab "Refreshes" (i.e. redirects) to another url.

Advertising companies seem to use this trick to bypass adblocking software.

Answer (score 2):

Just ditch Chrome and use Firefox. Firefox already have built-in mouse-click popups. I think all addons like Adguard or Adblock can not disable mouse-click popups. If you use Firefox, these are the steps:

1. Type about:config in the browser's address bar and hit the enter key.
2. First time users need to confirm that they be careful on the next page.
3. Type or paste dom.popup_allowed_events into the search field.
4. The value of the preference highlights all events that are allowed to spawn popups.
5. Edit the value to remove some or all of the items here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a browser extension such as AdBlock?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en

Comment: Because they don't block click under ads.

Answer (score 0):

My go-to is right click and open in new tab. onClick events only happen with a left click. It's cumbersome but it still ends up being less work than closing the pop-up and whatever annoying prompts it may have.

Answer (score 0):

I do not there's a practical solution for this.

Moreover, I think some of the answers here are missing the specific case in OP, where clicking anywhere on the page will cause the pop up to happen, not just clicking on links. According to this, neither right-clicking then choosing "open", nor noticing and blocking the target URL will help. I do not know of an add blocker that helps here either, because it's not trivial to meaningfully filter a click event that is taking place on the whole page object.

Only the solution provided by @Monkey would work, at the drawback of possibly breaking other things.